# as3 can I do this on one line

Tags: actionscript-3, casting, movieclip, get-childitem

Hi I can go this

```
var firstname = firstname_mc;
var fname = firstname.getChildAt(0).text;
```

but

```
var firstname = MovieClip(firstname_mc).getChildAt(0).text;
```

does not work

Comment: the usual - Access of possibly undefined property through a reference with static type Class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `firstname_mc` is not a `MovieClip` instance. Maybe it is an instance of `DisplayObjectContainer`? Therefore casting fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
var firstname = TextField(MovieClip(firstname_mc).getChildAt(0)).text;
```

Assuming, **firstname_mc** is a movieclip with a textfield inside that you are trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

If firstname_mc is a movieclip or sprite:

```
var firstname = TextField(firstname_mc.getChildAt(0)).text;
```

However, your screwed if you add another movieclip inside the firstname_mc, right under the textfield. Then you are not sure its the child at 0.. So why not give it the textfield a name (like "label_txt")? Then you can do much shorter syntax:

```
var firstname = firstname_mc.label_txt.text;
```